# Routing HTTP Based on Source IP in HAProxy

Tags: http, routes, load-balancing, haproxy

I've been reading through HAProxy's documentation, and I could not seem to find a way to route HTTP requests based on the source IP address. That is, I want to route specific sources to specific backend servers. For example, I want to route any request that's coming from 10.1.0.3 to one specific server.

Comment: Check out http://serverfault.com/questions/502487/haproxy-load-balancing-based-on-source-ip-ip-subnet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ACL for this king of settings.

Example:

```
  acl sub1 src 192.168.0.0/24
  acl sub2 src 192.168.1.0/24

  use backend back1 if sub1
  use backend back2 if sub2
```

Then you have to declare both backend server back1 and back2

I hope this help.
Regards,